# Spark streaming context using RDD

Tags: apache-spark, streaming, rdd

Does `rdd.context()` give same context as `ssc.sparkContext()` ?

```
ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, new Duration(5000));
```

and rdd is generated from ssc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes rdd.Context() returns the `SparkContext` that this RDD was created on.